# Retrieving external JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to be able to retrieve and display JSON data from a website for the application I am making. Before implementing it into my application, I thought I should make sure I understand how it works by testing it elsewhere. I made the following HTML and JSON code to test it, but if I run the application I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html:11
What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.get('testData.json', function(data) {
                alert('get performed');
                var obj = eval ("(" + data + ")");
                $("p").html(obj.data_set[0].data1);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Display</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file:

```
[{"data_set":{"data1":"string","data2":null,"data3":22.0}}]
```

Comment: You're using `eval` which is unnecessary. I suggest you read about [what JSON is and how to use it](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$.get` to `$.getJSON` or set the datatype in your $.get called like this

**UPDATE**

I also realized that you're not parsing the json correctly tried like this

```
 $.get('testData.json', function(data) {
     alert('get performed');
     $("p").html(obj[0].data_set.data1);
 },'json');
```

Comment: Changing `$.get` to `$.getJSON` gives me the error Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier at file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html:1

Comment: That works, however I still get the error in my last comment if I include `'json'` or change the url to the actual website I'm trying to access. The json data for the website is structured the same as the sample I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `eval` which is unnecessary. I suggest you read about [what JSON is and how to use it](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/.).

You don't need to use `eval` on `data` because it is already a JSON object. The problem with your code is that you're trying to access `data_set` as a property of `data`. However, `data` is really an array, with one unnamed object. That object has the member `data_set`. In turn, `data_set` is an object, not an array, so you cannot use `data_set[0]`. You want to have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON('testData.json', function(data) {
            alert('get performed');
            $("p").html(data[0].data_set.data1);
        });
    });
});​
```

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jS3yW/)

Comment: Using `data[0]` instead of `data_set[0]` works as Jorge suggested above, but removing `var obj = eval ("(" + data + ")");` and changing the line below it to `$("p").html(data[0].data_set.data1);` gives me the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data1' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/projectName.html:10

Comment: I copied the exact JSON data I posted and pasted it back into the testData.json and then replaced my code between the second set of script tags with the code that you provided in your original comment and I still get that error. However if I change `$.get` to `$.getJSON` then it works.

Answer (score 0):

See this jsFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Uxtg/

I included some code to traverse the whole data-structure (not just one possible path). Take the part you need ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/gh/gist/response.json/37ab4c69a04628428ce2',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                // to display everything
                /*$.each(json, function (k, v) {
                    $.each(v.data_set, function (key, value) {
                        $('p').append(value);
                    });
                });*/

                // to display just the string
                $('p').html(json[0].data_set.data1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```